# Default values for arguments in C

Tags: c, function, arguments

Say I have a function in C defined as :

```
bool check ( int x, int y);
```

Now if I call it using `check(4);`

What will be the value of `y` that is taken?

Comment: will it be even compiled successfully?

Comment: It would read the second value of the stack and store it in `y`. Undefined behavior.

Comment: @jsn: Nothing in the language definition suggests that it would do anything with the stack; the standard doesn't even mention the word.

Comment: @KeithThompson Oh, I'm sorry. The Stack. There we go.

Comment: Why do you suppose that the `4` matches the first parameter? It could be that you "forgot" the first and not the second parameter.

Comment: @jsn: Could you clarify your clarification? It's true that most implementations use a contiguous stack, and the behavior you describe is likely, but there are no guarantees.

Comment: @KeithThompson C'mon people. Are we really going to get stuck on the pedantic semantics of the C spec? As I said, it is undefined behaivor, anything could happen. On most implementation without parameter matching, it would read the next value on the stack and will store it in the `y` variable. Obviously, that data might have been very important, so there is a high chance the program will crash. Do you expect all comments to be this big? The reason why I posted it as a comment and not as an answer is because it obviously doesn't answer everything, nor a comment should in normal circumstances.

Comment: @jsn: My point is that the behavior you described is not guaranteed. Even on systems with a contiguous stack, the behavior could vary depending on the order in which parameter are passed; I could easily imagine `x` being set to garbage and `y` to 4. (If you had written "could" rather than "should", I wouldn't have responded.) IMHO it's important to know what "undefined behavior" really means.

Comment: @DiegoDeVita It will if the declaration and use are in different translation units. The result will be undefined behavior (unless the definition agrees with the usage, taking only one parameter in the absence of a prototype, with the declaration being the odd man out).

Answer (score 7):

Code like this can possibly compile only if the function is either undeclared (C89/90) or declared without a prototype (C89/90 and C99).

In any case the behavior will be undefined. If the number and/or type of promoted arguments used in the call do not match those used in the function definition, the behavior is undefined.

> **6.5.2.2 Function calls**
>
> 6 [...] If the number of arguments does not equal the number of parameters, the
> behavior is undefined [...] If the function is defined with a type that does not include a prototype, and the
> types of the arguments after promotion are not compatible with those of the parameters
> after promotion, the behavior is undefined

Comment: A compiler is still permitted to reject the program; that's one possible consequence of undefined behavior.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Right, declarations are mandatory (as of C99), but prototypes are still optional, even as of C11. (Which is a pity, IMHO; non-prototype function declarations have been "obsolescent" since 1989.)